# Replace numpy arrays in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame with a combination of `numpy.ndarray` and categorical variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'i': [0, 1, 2],
                   'a': [np.array([]), np.array([]), 'A']
                 })

df['a'][0]

array([], dtype=float64)
```

I'd like to replace the `arrays` with `np.nan`.

I tried: `df['a'].replace(np.array([]), np.nan)` but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to replace empty arrays only or all arrays?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace empty arrays by `nan`, you can convert the column `a` as boolean mask:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].where(df['a'].astype(bool), np.nan)
print(df)

# Output
   i    a
0  0  NaN
1  1  NaN
2  2    A
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be checking with `isinstance`:

```py
# on one column
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) else x)

#whole df
df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) else x)
```